# Is it necessary to have a confirmed itinerary for a Schengen visa application?

Tags: visas, schengen, spain, tourist-visas

I am applying for a uniform Schengen visa of up to 90 days from Spain for tourism. My point of entry and exit from the Schengen area would be Spain itself for which I would attach the flight bookings. I'll also attach the necessary hotel bookings I've made in Spain. However, in the application, it does ask me about any other Destination State(s) I would be visiting and hence the corresponding proof of accommodation. Since my plan to visit other countries other than Spain is subject to change, should I mention any other countries/bookings in the application?

Would I still be allowed to visit other countries if I get the visa?
Also, is it possible to later on change the point of entry or exit as long as Spain remains my main destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you need to provide an itinerary for the duration of your stay in the Schengen Zone. If you declare that you are going to stay for the whole duration in Spain, and get the visa, this does not preclude you from travelling to other Schengen member states unless you get a  limited territorial validity visa. That being said, you should not wilful mislead a Schengen member state during the application phase.

Comment: Not trying to mislead. My question was, what if the itinary is not 'confirmed' and expected to change so what are the consequences?

Comment: I don't think you will be penalised for reasonable changes. You are not required to have a confirmed itinerary but one that shows that you have a plan and the requisite means of supporting yourself during your journey. You can cancel a hotel and book another one after you have received your Schengen visa. When do you expect the plan to be confirmed by? Before or after you are supposed to collect your visa? I didn't have confirmed bookings last year and I got a Schengen visa from Spain, but I did have an itinerary and prebooked flights and hotels (but not fully paid for).